# difference between file descriptor and socket file descriptor

Tags: c, sockets

Can I bind a file descriptor returned by open call to a socket?

I am trying to do something like,

```
 filefd = open("path",O_RDWR);

 ...

 bind (filefd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
 connfd = accept (filefd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen);
```

Why does the accept call return -1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an applications point of view, the difference is how you create and use the descriptor. Some system-calls can take any kind of descriptor, while others require a specific type of descriptor.

In your case the [`bind`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) call would have returned `-1` too, if you checked for the error. When a system-call returns `-1` you should check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to see what went wrong. You can use [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to get a printable string of the error, or [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to print it directly.

Comment: is it possible for a file and socket to share same fd ?

Comment: @SagarPatni No. You can actually think of descriptors as indexes into an array, and if you have two different indexes they will "point" to different places in the array.

Comment: what i am trying to do is , provide a socket over character device , for that the overhead of system call is too large , so somehow i am trying to map both files